# How to set Secret for github webhook in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I would like to set a secret text in my WebHook in github I don't know where I can set up it in Jenkins 2.138.3 with the GitHub plugin 1.23.9

Comment: any idea how you resolved this?

Answer (score 10):

Jenkins side:

1. Set a new credential: Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Credentials -> Add credential -> Secret Text

[image]
2. Configure GitHub plugin: Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> System -> GitHub -> Advanced -> Shared secret -> Add shared secret -> Pick the credential created in step 1.

[image]

GitHub side:

1. Settings -> Webhooks -> Manage Webhooks -> Secret -> Paste the credential text created in step 1.

[image]

I hope the instructions work for you (please update them after any UI changes).